# How to render different content in html tag in for loop?

Tags: angular

I have this *ngFor Loop. It render after each second element a h1 tag. Now I need to render different content in this tag

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let card of cards; index as i">
    <mat-card>
        <div class="left">
            <a class="title" target="_blank">
                {{card.title}}
            </a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="bottom">
                <a class="date" target="_blank">
                    <small>{{card.pages}}</small>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </mat-card>
    <h1 *ngIf="(i % 2) == 1">First tag</h1>
</ng-container>
```

Exemple [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gCPP.png)

Comment: and the actual code that does what you are saying?

Comment: I need to render something like this: 
First rendering of h1 tag with content "Its first tag"
Second rendering with this tag but with other content 
and so on

Comment: Sure but you wrote it does someting eachj second - which I cannot see how.  Long story short - swap content of h1 via field or part of card model.

Comment: I suggest that your array of object "card", to have a new property "h1Text" (-only neccesary for the even elements-). NOTE: You can use in *ngFor, `let even=even` and ask about `even` see the [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <h1 *ngIf="(i % 2) == 1">{{h2Content}}</h1>
```

in component

```
interval(1000).subscribe(()=>this.h2Content="SomeNewContentTakenFromSomewhereElse"));
```

this will allow you to assign new content to `this.h2Content` somehow (its up to you how)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can divide your index by two?

```html
<h1 *ngIf="(i % 2) == 1"> This is the {{(i+1)/2}}th content </h1>
```

and use this value to determine the `h1` content.